# How to write Xamarin.UITest case for Software Back Button on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I am writing UITest cases for my Xamarin forms project. Now, i am stuck at Navigation Part. I know using "app.Back()" we can navigate back but on our Project Hardware Back Button is disabled. Is there any way we can use Navigation Bar "Back button" ?

I tried to get elements in Page by using following code "AppResult[] results = app.Query();" but still i am not able to find any element which says barbackbutton or backbutton etc in the list.

Comment: You could customize the navigation bar of  the page .And then set the Id of the button . Check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47765/how-to-press-the-up-button-on-the-navbar-rather-than-the-back-button .

Comment: Is this interacting with your own app or an existing one, such as the browser?

Comment: @klreeher : With our own App

Answer (score 2):

Bharat, after reading this a couple times, I think what you are asking is "how do I find the automation ids / elements to target".

There's a couple different ways to do this. My preferred one is `App.Repl()`. [Here's the Microsoft docs on it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/working-with-repl?tabs=vswin), but in short:

- at the point in your test where you are on the application view that you want to find an element on, put in `App.Repl()`

```
        [Test]
        public void CanTapButton()
        {
            App.Repl();
        }
```

Run the test. When the test gets to this point, a repl window will open and the test will pause. End the test if you want, but keep the command window. It will look like this:
[image: screenshot of ios command prompt open to xamarin ui test repl]

Type into the command prompt `tree`, to see the full layout of the page visible on the device.
[image: Repl Tree on ios]

You can use the app query calls in the Repl window to draft queries. For example,

`app.Query(x => x.Marked("cpgTitle"));`

will return the `cpgTitle` element that you can see listed in the tree. You can then use that app query to interact with the element, using something like `App.Tap(appQueryVariable)`.

AppQueries docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.uitest.queries.appquery?view=xamarin-uitest-sdk) and overall, it's very similar to selenium-style selectors.

Comment: Oh, one note -- if you/your team add automation ids, these queries get a lot more platform-agnostic, but currently with Xamarin, you can't actually get automation ids to show up in Shell elements. Most other elements will work with automation ids tho.

Comment: Thanks. What about Android ?? Android just have back arrow button right ?

Comment: If the hardware button for Android is locked down too, you will likely have problems with the [`App.Back`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.uitest.iapp.back?view=xamarin-uitest-sdk#Xamarin_UITest_IApp_Back) method. However, you can use Repl exactly the same on Android.

If you use an automation id, the query should be the same on ios and android.

Comment: From the information given on the question, using Repl() should deffo help achieve what you want. +1 for this answer from me.